# How do I get google drive file id after uploading using google Drive api?

Tags: php, laravel, codeigniter, google-api, google-drive-api

I'am using PHP Google Drive Api ([Uploading files to Google Drive with PHP](https://github.com/fareed543/Uploading-files-to-Google-Drive-with-PHP)) to upload files on google drive and I want to know how to get the fileId after uploading, so I can use it as the SRC in HTML. Does someone knows? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to stack.  please edit your question include the code you are using and describe any issues you are having with that code.  you may also want to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

You can find the answer to your question in [examples](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/blob/master/examples/simple-file-upload.php#L92) from official [Google's API PHP Client repository](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client):

```
$file = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
$result = $service->files->create(
    $file,
    [
      'data' => file_get_contents('path/to/your/file'),
      'mimeType' => 'application/octet-stream',
      'uploadType' => 'media',
    ]
);

// $result->id is the ID you're looking for
// $result->name is the name of uploaded file
```

See the HTML example below, how you can use the `$result` object:

```
<a href="https://drive.google.com/open?id=<?= $result->id ?>" target="_blank"><?= $result->name ?>
```

Comment: The example is broken; `$service->files->create()` actually returns a Guzzle Request object, which doesn't have any of the file fields. :(